# Using Realm to save a title from a textfield in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm not sure how to save a title from a textfield into Realm. CurrentNote and note are both from Note, a swift file with dynamic vars including title.

```
func saveNote() {
    currentNote = Note()
    note = currentNote
    if let note = note {
        let realm = Realm()

        var index = tableView[]
        var changingNote:Note = Note()
            changingNote.title = index
            realm.write{
                realm.add(note)
                self.notes = realm.objects(Note)
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could something like the following work?

```
func saveNote(noteIndex: Int) {
  let note = notes[noteIndex]
  note.realm.write {
    note.title = TITLE
  }
}
```